# Prevent Skype resolvers getting your IP on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 14.10, security, skype

I am running Skype version `4.3.0.37` on Ubuntu 14.10, and I know that on the Windows version there is an option to only allow direct connections to your machine through Skype for Skype contacts, which thus means that Skype resolvers cannot resolve your IP.

But on the Skype version for Ubuntu there is no such option, so I was wondering if this could be somehow still achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following command:

```
gedit ~/.Skype/YourSkypeName/config.xml
```

Search for `<Account>` and add in that section:

```
<PrivateSkypeMode>1</PrivateSkypeMode>
```

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Very useful and simple ! +1